# Protracter filter called many times

Tags: typescript, filter, protractor, autotest

I have a grid of flight information with some rows, which contains properties like flight number. Now, I want to filter the row based on a target flight number `flightno`. Here, the value of `flightno` is 15984234. The codes are shown below

```js
let trTarget = element.all(by.css('[kendogridlogicalrow]')).filter(tr => {
  return tr.all(by.css("[data-kendo-grid-column-index='1']")).getText().then(cellstxt => {
    console.log(cellstxt + '++++')
    console.log('1')
    if (cellstxt.includes(FlightNo)) {
      console.log(cellstxt + '----')
      console.log('2')
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}).first()

trTarget.getText().then(cellstxt => {
  console.log(cellstxt + '&&&&')
  console.log('3')
})
```

These codes are wrapped as a function `locateTrWithId`, which returns trTarget.

In the place which call the function, codes are shown below

```js
let trTarget = this.locateTrWithId(flightno);
var ele = trTarget.all(by.tagName('a')).first()
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(ele), 10000)
ele.getText().then(txt => {
  console.log(txt + '*****')
  console.log('4')
})
ele.close()
```

The function `locateTrWithId` works normally, but when I try to print some details, I found something interesting, see the console.log results

```js
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234----
2
p&&&&
3
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234----
2
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234----
2
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234----
2
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234----
2
15984234*****
4
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234----
2
```

As shown in the screenshot, the part of filter is called five times, one of which is executed with the part of get text from the filtered trTarget (print 3), others are executed independently

Another thing is after calling and executing the function `locateTrWithId`, and get text of return trTarget (print 4), the filter is executed again!

Here are parts of the corresponding HTML codes

```html
<tr kendogridlogicalrow="" data-kendo-grid-item-index="0" role="row" class="ng-star-inserted">...</tr>
<tr kendogridlogicalrow="" data-kendo-grid-item-index="1" role="row" class="ng-star-inserted">...</tr>
<tr kendogridlogicalrow="" data-kendo-grid-item-index="2" role="row" class="ng-star-inserted">
  <td kendogridcell="" kendogridlogicalcell="" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" data-kendo-grid-column-index="0" colspan="1" aria-colindex="1" class="ng-star-inserted">...</td>
  <td kendogridcell="" kendogridlogicalcell="" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" data-kendo-grid-column-index="1" colspan="1" aria-colindex="2" class="ng-star-inserted"><a href="#/admin/manifest-detail/30707" class="ng-star-inserted"> 15984234</a>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Please explain this. Many thanks!

Comment: I've actually asked a very similar question [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/35575/elementarrayfinder-filter-how-does-it-work-under-the-hood) that was never really answered. I would like to know why it goes through each element multiple times as well. I doubt we will ever know for sure unless we dig into the code ourselves and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution to avoid calling filter so many times

```js
private locateTrWithId(GridIndex: number, FlightNo: string) {
  let tbTarget = this.opr.locateTb(GridIndex);

  var tdswithhyperlink = tbTarget.all(by.tagName('a'))
  tdswithhyperlink.each(td => {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(td), 10000)
  })
  return tbTarget.all(by.css('[kendogridlogicalrow]')).filter(tr => {
    tr.element(by.css("[data-kendo-grid-column-index='1']")).getText().then(txt => {
      console.log(txt + '++++')
      console.log('1')
    })
    return tr.all(by.css("[data-kendo-grid-column-index='1']")).getText().then(cellstxt => {
      if (cellstxt.includes(FlightNo)) {
        console.log(cellstxt + '++++')
        console.log('2')
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }).first().element(by.tagName('a')).click()
}
```

Here, I integrate the click action to the filter action (so I remove the parts of get Text of returned/filtered trTarget). The execution result is

```js
15983767++++
1
15984065++++
1
15984234++++
1
15984234++++
2
```

But I cannot explain the reason....